# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).editRule is not a function - click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, typeerror

I am totally confused and googled a lot but did not find the answer. No matter what I try, the following Code causes: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).editRule is not a function.

```
    functionName(){
         [...]    
         $(`#index`).unbind().click(() => {
            $(`#index`).editRule(rule);
          });
      }

      editRule (rule) {
        // do sth
      }
```

The reference definitely works. Other predefined functions like .remove() behaves correctly. I tried a lot (function or static, no parameter, other functions, etc.) but the error stays and I am not very experienced with the click-event. Does somebody know what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you using backticks `\`` instead of quotes in your selectors? `$(\`#ruleIndex${rule.index}-edit\``

Comment: What api are you referencing that lets you know that `editRule` is a jQuery method?

Comment: @j08691 Those are ES6 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: @j08691 He's using template literals to build the selector, no?

Comment: @Taplar It´s a self-written method

Comment: Then take a look at the answer below.  Can you explain why you are under the impression that a self made method will automatically be included as part of the jQuery namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the `editRule` method to jQuery using : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/ ? Or are you using a special jQuery library that would add `editRule` to jQuery's methods?

Otherwise `editrule` is not a jQuery method and cannot be chained like this.

Comment: okay that seems evident... but when I change everything and make a function in which I deliver the selected Object as a parameter, I get the same Error ( editRule($(`#ruleIndex${rule.index}`) )

Comment: Well, you cannot be having the exact same error since you are not calling `$(...).editRule` anymore.